How do I determine if the set of complex numbers defined by the relation $|z - 3i| \geq 1$ is open, closed or neither?
I'm confused on this a question on complex number planes, and whether the mentioned set is closed, open or neither.
$ |z - 3i| \ge 1$
I'm guessing that this set is neither open nor closed, since it contains all of its boundary points at $|z-3i| = 1$ but does not contain the boundary points, since the rest of set stretches to infinity.
Also, are there any general tips to figure out if a set is open or closed or neither, especially with the sets that involve a " $\ge$ " operation?

I see partly where you got snagged,  but since the complement is the open unit disk centered at $3i,$ it's closed.

Notice the function $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ defined by $f(z) := |z - 3i|$ is continuous. Then you are interested in the set $A := f^{-1}([1,+\infty))$. Given that the set $[1,+\infty)$ is closed, then one concludes that the set $A$ is closed as well.
Hopefully this helps!

But this is what is confusing me:
A closed set must have a clearly defined boundary. In this case, the set extends into infinity. In that case, how can it have a clearly defined boundary? In one way, it seems to be open and in another way, it seems to be closed

@DimSum010 One says that a set is closed if its complement is open (and $(-\infty,1)$ is open).

That makes more sense, thank you so much :)

@DimSum010 you are welcome! I am glad I could help.

A closed set needn't have a 'clearly defined' boundary. It only has to contain all its boundary points if it has any. A set without a boundary is therefore both closed and open (e.g., the whole $\mathbb C$ and its complement in $\mathbb C$, namely the empty set). See clopen set at Wikipedia.

By definition of the close set: the complement set of an open set is a closed set. The complement set of interest is $|z - 3i| < 1$ is definitely an open set, thus the set $|z - 3i| >= 1$ is a closed set.
Maybe you can concentrate on the definition of open set and close set to figure out a set in complex plane is open set or close set.
Hopefully this helps!!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You can say $\mid z-3i\mid \lt1$ is the open disk of radius $1$ centered at $3i.$  Hence it is open.

A set S in the complex plane is open if for every point P in the set, we can open ball that includes P with every point in that ball in S.
The disk $D = \{z|\ |z|<3\}$ is an open set.  For any $z\in D$ we can define a disk with radius $\frac {3-|z|}{2}$ and every point in that disk is also in D.
The complex plane, itself, is then an open set.  The empty set is also an open set.  Since there are no points in the empty set, it does not violate our definitions.
We can define a set as closed if its complement is open.
$S = \{z|\ |z|>3\}$ is an open set.
$S^c = \{z|\ |z|\le 3\}$ is a closed set.
Since the complement of the complex plane is the empty set, the entire plane (and the empty set), are also closed sets.
The union of open sets is an open set.
$S = \{z|\ |z|>3\}\cup \{z|\ |z|<3\}$ is the union of open sets.
$S^c = \{z|\ |z|=3\}$ is a closed set.
That closed sets include their accumulation points is a consequence of these definitions.
Hope this helps.
